# C++ ( MS V S ) GetOpenFileName

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi

My program is meant to let the user open 2 files and then compare them in a specific manner. I'm using Visual Studio to create this in C++ with a GUI (please correct me if it's not the best way, I only know how to code C on Linux):

```
OPENFILENAME open;
ZeroMemory(&open, sizeof(open));

open.lStructSize = sizeof(LPOPENFILENAMEA);
open.lpstrFilter = "Files\0*.csv;*.xls\0\0";
open.nFileOffset = 1;
open.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
open.nMaxFile = 2048;
open.lpstrTitle = "Title here.";
open.Flags = OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;
BOOL selected = GetOpenFileName(&open);
```

I'm getting the following compiler errors:

```
E0513   a value of type "const char *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "LPCWSTR"    

Error   C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'const char [39]' to 'LPCWSTR' NewTry
```

On both the `filter` and `title` lines.

Comment: Let me guess, you're building with Unicode enabled (i.e. the `UNICODE` macro is defined)? That means just about all strings needs to be wide-character strings. This is one of the reasons for the `T` macro. Modify your string literals like e.g. `T("Title here.")`

Comment: When I do that I'm getting different errors, identifier T is not found / undefined

Comment: No, don't use TCHAR macros. Use the `L` prefix, @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @DavidHeffernan While having Unicode enabled should be the default IMO, by hard-coding wide-character literals you have the opposite problem to this if the code is used in a build or project where `UNICODE` is not defined. Or for code that might be used cross-platform. I dislike the use of the the T macros as much as anyone, but until the old non-Unicode interface is removed it's unfortunately the best compromise I think.

Comment: This code can't be used cross platform, and it makes no sense to support Windows 95 these days. It's 2017. Time to move on.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan _it makes no sense to support Windows 95 these days_ -
This is a little bit black and white. For instance, the [recent version of Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/910_b1.htm) is still available for Win 9x, so there seems to be a demand for it. Not everyone in this world can afford to upgrade to the latest and greatest hardware every year.

Comment: @zett: True, but do you know how many second-hand computers became available when Windows XP support was officially dropped? Upgrading yearly isn't necessary, buying new hardware isn't needed. And TBH when I supported Windows 98, 12 years ago, I did so by shipping MSLU (Microsoft Layer For Unicode). Still a better solution than `TCHAR`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: FYI, you are thinking of the `_T()` macro, not `T()`.  And note that `_T()` only applies to the C runtime library, not the Win32 API.  The Win32 API equivalent is the `TEXT()` macro instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau IIRC the `_T` and `_TEXT` and other macros starting with a leading underscore are related to `_UNICODE`, and there are corresponding macros (including `T`) without leading underscore related to `UNICODE`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you recall partially correct. The C runtime uses `_TCHAR`, `_T()` (and other underscore-prefixed macros/defines), and `_UNICODE`. The Win32 API uses `TCHAR`, `LP(C)TSTR`, `TEXT()`, and `UNICODE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Windows 95/98/ME are **long** dead, the current recommendation is to use the native Unicode support of the Windows NT series of Operating Systems.

You already got that setup, apparently, since the error message tells us that `GetOpenFileName` is defined as `GetOpenFileNameW`. On WIndows 95, it was defined as `GetOpenFileNameA`. The `A` variant means it takes `const char*` arguments, the `W` variant takes `const wchar_t*`.

You define `wchar_t` wide string literals with the `L` prefix, i.e. `L"Files..."`. You can also use `std::wstring`, it's `c_str()` method returns a null-terminated `const wchar_t*`.

Comment: I've tried the L prefix and it leads me to even more errors as mentioned in the above comments.

Comment: @C.Edelweiss: I think you mean in answer to Sean's post (above and below can vary a bit as answers are upvoted). But those unresolved symbols mean that your code **compiles**. It fails later, in **linking**. That means the compilation question here is solved. As for the linker error, that's of course a matter of adding the libraries used.

Comment: @C.Edelweiss You seem to have given up. You are just trying suggestions from the answers and when you get subsequent unrelated failures, come back here for more. Try to think and about what you are doing, and understand it. The question you asked has been answered. You now have a new problem. Don't ask a new question, there are thousands of existing questions asked about your new problem. Indeed there are thousands asked about the problem in this question. In future you should try to read error messages, and do some independent research. Don't just give up!

Comment: I'm looking into them right now, seems to be a lot of possibilities and it's not easy getting to this environment when I pretty mutch did C on Linux, thanks for the information.

Comment: @C.Edelweiss: Well, undefined symbols in linking are pretty much the same in C for Linux. Might not actually be named `LNK2019`, but the concept is the same. And `LNK2019` is easy to search here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @MSalters Never actually had one of them in C, everything was pretty much fixable with -g3 and valgrind or even test printfs :/

Comment: I did somehow manage to fix those, no clue how, but now when i'm testing the button that's supposed to call getopenfilename, the program stops responding

Comment: Well, that's past the linking phase. And again, you'll find that Visual Studio is an improvement - it's debugger is way ahead of gdb.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're doing a unicode build.

If you look at the definition of one on the string structure members, such as `lpstrFilter` you'll see that it's defined as `LPTSTR`. The first `T` means that the text type is either ASCII or Unicode, depending on how you're building.

To handle both scenarios use the `_T` macro when entering string literals:

```
open.lpstrFilter = _T("Files\0*.csv;*.xls\0\0");
```

This will give you a ASCII string on non-Unicode builds, and a Unicode string on Unicode builds.

If you only wish to target Unicode then you can explicitly get a Unicode string by prefixing the string with a `L`:

```
open.lpstrFilter = L"Files\0*.csv;*.xls\0\0";
```

Microsoft how detailed information on their [Unicode Programming Summary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dybsewaf.aspx) page.

Comment: Both methods give me 17 new errors pointing to line 1, which is #include <windows.h>, most are Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__CreateSolidBrush@4 referenced in function _WinMain@16 NewTry C:\Users\Robert\source\repos\NewTry\NewTry\NewTry.obj 1         Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _wWinMain@16 referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ) NewTry //LIBCMTD.lib(exe_wwinmain.obj)

Comment: Pretty hard to get behind an answer that suggests supporting Windows 95.

Comment: @C.Edelweiss - those are linker errors. You need to ensure that you are linking with the correct libraries.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - large chucks of the MSDN still use these macros, so it's hardly unreasonable to mention them in an example.

Comment: Those MSDN examples set a very poor lead. Don't follow them. Don't perpetuate this awful TCHAR mess.

Comment: Besides all that, there is a superfluous `\0` character at the end of the filter string. While being harmless, this is still wrong, and should have been noted.